# Spring tests: No qualifying bean error for code with @NoRepositoryBean implementation

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have three classes Vehicle, Car and Truck. The Vehicle class has all the common properties from Car and Truck class and is marked as @NoMappedBean

Here is how the classes looks like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
class Vehicle {
    Long key;
    String color;
    String engineType;
    String transmissionType;
}

@Entity
class Car {
    Long id;
    String carType;
}

@Entity
class Truck {
    Long id;
    boolean isMpv;
}


@NoRepositoryBean
public interface VehicleRepository<T extends Vehicle> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    //code to call the respective queries
}


public interface CarRepository extends VehicleRepository<Car> {}

public interface CarRepository extends VehicleRepository<Truck> {}
```

The above code works fine on my service layer when I run the application. Now I am trying to write test cases for my service layer in the following code.

```
@SpringBootTest
class TestCases {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleRepository<Car> carRepository;
    
}
```

Here when I am autowiring `VehicleRepository<Car>` I am getting the following error:

```
com.jpa.demo.service.ProcessService required a bean of type 'com.jpa.demo.dao.VehicleRepository' that could not be found.
No qualifying bean of type 'com.jpa.demo.dao.VehicleRepository<com.jpa.demo.model.Car>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Any help in solving this would be appreciated. Thank you!